# E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error) E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Tags: apt

This all started when a red dot appeared on the menu bar.

Machine was operating poorly so I read the message that stated there was an error run package manager so I followed a thread to a person with the same message and run the recommended command and got the following message

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-en-base libhal1 hal libhal-storage1
  hal-info
```

So I ran the command that was to remove them and terminal claimed success. I still have the previous mentioned error reported on the menu bar.

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

machine is performing about the same except the Software Center crashes.

Comment: Please edit your question adding which command you launched to get that message

Comment: Tony, tehre's no mention of any error in your question. Is this the error you're having? `(E:read error-read (5: input/output error),E: the package list or status file could not be parsed or opened.)` If so, add it t your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your system no longer needs those packages and is letting you know that you can remove them if you want. If you read the next line on your screen (in the terminal where you copied this from) you'll notice it says that you can run `apt-get autoremove` to remove these packages.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-en-base libhal1 hal
 libhal-storage1 hal-info
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: i did the above claimed success full but still getting an error so I tony@tony-ThinkPad-Z61m:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
tony@tony-ThinkPad-Z61m:~$

Comment: the software center fails to start as well. error opening the cache (E:read error-read (5: input/output error),E: the package list or status file could not be parsed or opened.)

Comment: Tony. You're going to have to reword you original question to mention this. It doesn't have any details as to what your issue is.

Answer (score 2):

If you look to the whole message, not only the portion you post but the rest of the output too, it suggests that you run the **autoremove** command of **apt**

So, if you run `sudo apt-get autoremove`, you will get rid of these packages you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, just a message telling you there are packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies, but which are no longer needed.

So if there *was* an error--for example, if it said "error" or other text to tell you there was a problem--then the `were automatically installed` message is *separate from it*. You'd then have to provide more information (what you were trying to accomplish, what command you ran, its *complete* output, and any other information you think might be relevant), to get an answer.